# How to snap part of a mesh to the grid?

Tags: mesh, workflow, edit-mode, snapping

I have an I-Beam where one end is on the grid and the other end is between grid lines. When I turn on "snap to grid" and moves all vertexes in the other end it snaps in grid *increments*, not to the grid itself.

Do I really have to create a dummy on the grid to be able to snap to it?

Blender v2.69

**EDIT**
I'm aware of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and it works fine for simple meshes.  However this is what happens if you try the "Snap selected to grid" on a complex mesh:

[image]

Comment: What version of blender are you using? *Selection to grid* works fine for me in 2.69.

Answer (score 8):

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle Quad View, then click to the nearest grid crossing to place 3D Cursor there, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to Grid** to snap the 3D Cursor in two of the side views (to snap it precisely to the grid dimension as you want). Then, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > **Selection to Cursor (Offset)** to offset the selection to the 3D Curor, without collapsing:

[image]

**NOTE:** Snapping cursor to grid currently depends much on the view zooming, in other words, the visual grid scale, so, if it cannot be easily snapped to the crossing, just give it another try after zooming in or out.

---

**UPDATE:** For your concern in the comment, you can temporarily add an empty to assist snapping:

[image]

Comment: This looks like an effective way to do it, but it fails if the objects center isn't in right on the grid. If you move youre model down a bit and do the same you will see that the I-Beam "side" snap its center to the grid. If it isn't in center already, the model will be skewed.

Comment: @MaxKielland OK. Then I would suggest a relatively quick way to do this, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Method 1:

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*>Selection to Grid*.

[image]

For example:

[image]

## Method 2:

As an expansion of [Leon Cheung's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7386/599):

1. Snap the cursor to the selection:

   [image]
2. Snap the cursor to grid

   [image]
3. Snap the selection to the cursor with the *Offset* option

   [image]
4. The selection is now aligned with the grid, so you can snap using the normal increment snap.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for a complex shape like an I-Beam. All  selected vertices snapps to the same point nearest point, deforming the whole object. I will see if I can update with pictures.

Comment: I have updated my question with a picture of the SHIFT-S problem.

Comment: You can do this in orthographic mode and it uses the grid size of the current zoom level, _(however we could add some grid-division option for the snap tool as well.)_

Comment: It still snapps in grid increments, not to the actual grid itself. All I really want is so simple, press G to move the vertices, lock an axle and snap to the visual grid, without moving any vertice in any other direction than the locked one. How hard can it be?!?

Comment: @ideasman42 Or a 'Selection to Grid (Offset)' option?

Comment: @RayMairlot The default option seems to behave that way for me (in the 2.7 RC)..

Comment: @gandalf3 ah yes, you are right. I had presumed it didn't work like that from the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @MaxKielland Exactly, extremely frustrating that they cant such a simple thing right.  i cant find an answer that explains how to do it. Blender really seem to have messed up snapping, its over convoluted yet cant do basic stuff

Comment: @nights There is now a more convenient snap to grid option, I can't update my answer atm but try this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177745/599

Answer (score 3):

You can snap the cursor to the grid and add a plane at the cursor, merge all points of the plane into a single vertex. Than you can use vertex snap to snap the geometry to the plane.

1. Place the cursor some place near the grid point you wish to snap the geometry to.

[image]

2. Snap the cursor to the grid point

[image]

3. Add a plane whilst still in edit mode. With the plane selected merge all vertices at center

[image]

4. Now use vertex snap to snap your geometry to the vertex.

[image]

5. Make sure to delete the vertex when you are done with it.

---

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was what I meant with "create a dummy object". It is a hell of trouble to do a such fundamental thing :)

Comment: This is the method that I use, its not ideal but it works fine. And I don't do this anyway on a regular basis

Comment: So you have to add extra geometry just to snap to grid? Crazy!