# Scale with snap to grid messed up after scaling

Tags: snapping

I've got a - probably - very basic question.

I put a basic cube on a scene, resized it in one dimension to 18 units (so it is a long bar now), then used "Apply Scale". Now when I try to use scaling with snap-to-grid feature, the snap works but snaps not to the grid lines but some arbitrary values inbetween.

Also, I've noticed that snap works only for some directions, I've got a hunch that it is only for the longest one - in my case it is Y. Can I make it snap in other directions too?

[example of messed up snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veoRo.png)

Comment: You applied scale after making object to be a bar but didn't after scaling it once more (notice scale value by Y axis - 0.8). Apply scale once more. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Thanks. This is an example of already broken scaling, which is why scaling values are not 1,1,1. Unfortunately, in this case, even after re-applying scaling, it doesn't snap to grid.

I am pretty sure what it does has nothing to do with actual grid, the snap increment seems to be 10% of direction between rescaling... this also exaplains why it seems snap doesn't work for short dimensions - it works, but the increment is so small I didn't notice it. Ultimately - I still don't know how to scale with a real snap to grid :|

Comment: This is because you scaled that bar to its origin; it became a bit shorter and doesn't fit grid as for now. To snap it to grid use appropriate function, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7368/how-to-snap-part-of-a-mesh-to-the-grid

Comment: Hm, I know what you mean (snap->snap selection to grid), but that I can fix. 

What I do have problem is how to apply snapping during scaling, so the scaled object fits to the grid. For example, I have my 18-long bar, and the grid is set to 1 unit. Now, after one "tick" of scaling it becomes 16.2 long, and this is why it doesn't fit the grid anymore. As I expected scaling increments are 10% of the original dimensions. And this is where I am stuck - **how to have increment of 1 during scaling, regardless of original dimensions?** And btw, thanks for help! Thats huge for a newbie! :)

Comment: You could substitue snapping to grid with snapping to a subdivided plane where cells would be roughly of the same size (make sure enabling snapping to vertex while scaling). If you want to model with precision take a look at this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements