# Where is "Absolute Grid Snap" option in latest 2.8 release?

Tags: snapping

Where is "Absolute Grid Snap" option in latest 2.8 release?
It's not in the snap settings options?

Comment: in my version if you click on the snap menu, there's an Absolute Grid Snap option you can enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol has changed from

[image: this]

to

[image: that]

Comment: My bad, I wasn't paying attention. Thanks @miceterminator

Comment: I too am sometimes disoriented by the lack of familiar colours in the new symbols. No need to apologise.

Comment: I am working in the 2d animator interface of Blender, and cannot find that grid option (or other grid options) anywhere. It would be greatly appreciated, if you could explain where to find the option exactly?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I was having a hard time locating "Absolute Grid Snap" but it seems to be located center top in the drop down of "Snap to"

I also noticed if you click on the multiple options in "Snap to" more options pop up - 2nd image below.

[image]

I am new here feel free to correct me in my answer.